# Entity Framework Transaction across multiple SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, transactions, unity-container, entity-framework-6.1

I am creating an application which uses WCF (4.5), EF (6.1), Unity (3.5) and Unity3.Wcf (3.5)

The application needs to run a monthly process which checks for changes that have happened in last month and create a record for an approval process.

This process will be triggered by a call to a WCF service method.

This is the basic logic:

```
Get collection of Things

For each Thing:

    Get collection of ThingChanges

    Calculate changed Amount

    Create New ThingApproval

    Update each ThingChange in ThingChanges with ThingApproval.ID
```

Now, as far as I am aware, in order to get ThingApproval.ID, I need to do `SaveChanges` after `Create New ThingApproval` which will populate with the ID from the DB. I then need to do a further `SaveChanges` either after each `Update` or once after the for each completes to commit all the updates.

If any part of this process fails, it needs to rollback ALL changes, back to before the first `SaveChanges`

How can I implement this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Using Transactions or SaveChanges(false) and AcceptAllChanges()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges)

Comment: @GertArnold that doesn't specifically answer my question as it doesn't take into account my use of DI/IoC - I am not explicitly creating any scope

Comment: @GertArnold actually, I just read the second answer and that does seem to fit.

Comment: @GertArnold actually that doesn't help - my context is held in a repository class which is called by the application class so it doesn't have access to the context to set the transaction

Comment: "I am not explicitly creating any scope" No, that's the point. You should wrap everything in a `using TransactionScope` block, as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Last comment on the accepted answer: "This is no longer possible in EF 6.1. Do you know what kind of adjustments need to be made to work now?"

Comment: That only applies to this AcceptChanges method. It's still possible by the way, but you have to "descend" to the `ObjectContext`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655040/861716.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing the [GNaP.Data.Scope.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GNaP.Data.Scope.EntityFramework/) package which gives full control of the DB Context, including transactional.